# Policy for agents to view route

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to set up a policy where only agents can view their properties, and eventually only agents should be able to update their own properties. I want to also make it so that administrators will be able to go in and access ALL properties. Right now, I can't seem to do it and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
// this is my controller method
public function index($id)
{

    $this->authorize('view', $id);
    $properties = Property::where('agent_id', $id)->get();
    return view('agents.index', compact('properties'));
}


// this is in my PropertyPolicy
public function view(User $user, Agent $agent)
{
    return $agent->email_address == $user->email_address;
}
```

Comment: what model are you using for authentication in this case: `User` or `Agent`?

Comment: To be honest, I don't even think I have that specified, I first created a view where I could view all agent properties, but I think that Agent would be a suitable place since my User model would be more for people.

Comment: how is a `User` related to an `Agent` then?

Comment: I have to think about this

Comment: then how could you know who is an agent so that "only agents can view their propertie's"?

Comment: I think what I want is to separate the agent from the user and have an agent have their own login system, but I suppose that's another issue?

Comment: Right now I'm using User for authentication with the Laravel provided scaffolding

Comment: depends, a user is a concept to the authentication system, it could be any model or multiple models ... depends what you want ... might be easier to use `roles` at the moment or something to that degree so the same model is used for authentication everywhere with a check for what role they are instead of separate models ... but you have to figure that out before you can think about doing what you currently want to do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201147/discussion-between-user123-and-lagbox).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use App\Property;
use App\User;

public function view(User $user, Property $property)
{
    return $user->id === $property->agent_id;
}
```

You can check that the `id` of the current authenticated user matches the `agent_id` of the property (assuming this is how you setup the foreign key and relationship).

I am not sure if you are using the `User` model for authentication or the `Agent` model.

To allow admins to just pass through you can create a `before` method:

```
public function before($user, $ability)
{
    // how ever you determine if they are an admin
    if ($user->isAdmin()) {
        return true;
    }
}
```